# In how many ways can $5$ distinct figures be given to $3$ friends so that each friend receives at least one figure?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have 5 various figures. How many ways I can give figure to 3 friends, that every friend has at least one figure.

o - present figure

| - present friend

Choose:  o | o | o o o

$C^{*}{5+3-1 \choose 3-1}={7\choose2}=21$ ways

Is that correct result?

Comment: Are the figures considered distinct?

Comment: Yes there are   ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the figures are distinct, use inclusion/exclusion principle:

- Include the number of ways to give $5$ figures to $\color\red3$ out of $3$ friends: $\binom{3}{\color\red3}\cdot\color\red3^5=243$
- Exclude the number of ways to give $5$ figures to $\color\red2$ out of $3$ friends: $\binom{3}{\color\red2}\cdot\color\red2^5=96$
- Include the number of ways to give $5$ figures to $\color\red1$ out of $3$ friends: $\binom{3}{\color\red1}\cdot\color\red1^5=3$

Hence the number of ways is $243-96+3=150$.

Comment: Why you include the number of ways to give 5 figures to 1 out of 3 friends please?

Comment: @user4362081: You basically need to add "at most" before the red number in each bullet (I did not do so, because it would make the bullets stretch over more than a single line, making the answer less clear). So when you count the number of ways to give those figures to **at most** $3$ friends, you are counting the number of ways to give them to $3$, $2$ or $1$ friend. Then you subtract the number of ways to give them to **at most** $2$ people. When doing so, you are also double-subtracting the number of ways to give them to $1$ person, so you need to add it back into the count.

Answer (score 1):

The stars-and-bars approach you use is problematic in two ways:

- The figures are distinct, but the [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) approach is for indistinguishable objects.
- The stars-and-bars formula $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ includes friends getting no figures.

---

Another approach is: If friend $1$ gets $i$ figures, friend $2$ gets $j$ figures, and friend $3$ gets $5-i-j$ figures, then there are $$\binom{5}{i,j,5-i-j}=\frac{5!}{i!\,j!\,(5-i-j)!}$$ ways to distribute the figures to achieve this distribution.

We tabulate the possibilities:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
(i,j,5-i-j) & \binom{5}{i,j,5-i-j} \\
\hline
(3,1,1) & 20 \\
(2,2,1) & 30 \\
(2,1,2) & 30 \\
(1,3,1) & 20 \\
(1,2,2) & 30 \\
(1,1,3) & 20 \\
\hline
\text{total}: & 150
\end{array}
$$
agreeing with barak manos's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the figures are not distinct which is the case it looks like from your attempt. Let us say the $i$-th friend gets $x_i$ many figures then we have to count the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=5$ where each of $x_i \geq 1$. Or equivalently if we say $x_i=y_i+1$ then the number of solutions to the equation $y_1+y_2+y_3=2$ where $y_i \geq 0$. $\binom{3+2-1}{3-1}=\binom{4}{2}=6$.

Similar to what you tried but you did not allow condition $x_i \geq 1$.